# Get Object distributed with a specific pixels distance in photoshop.!

Tags: object, photoshop

There are 5 objects in a row which i want to distribute in a line
but i want 15 pixels distance between edges of objects in photoshop

what I am getting is `Distribution Object by center`, but not `same distance` between objects, How can i get it?

[image: Distribution of Objects]

Here's what i want (case 2) & what i get (case 1).

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: Make a 15px wide (and also quite tall) transparent *"spacer object"* and put a copy between other objects and then squish them all together :-) This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is zoom in to the pictures to the point of where you can literally count each pixel. And start adjusting each picture with the arrow keys.
Or draw a square that measures 15 pixels wide and duplicate it. Once you are done with adjustment you can delete the square.